# ag-grid data source with nested array

Tags: ag-grid

I have a remote row data source that comes from a JSON object that has 2 fields:  `status code`, `array of records`.  I want to show the row source in the grid asynchronously.  How would I go about doing that?

I understand the following syntax:

```
[rowData]="rowData | async"
```

That works great when the web service returns an array.  Just not sure how to do that in my case.

I've tried `observable.map(c => c["courses"]);`
and tried `observable.mergeMap(c => c["courses"]);`

Comment: Which `rowModel` do you use? When you talk about "nested arrays" I assume you want to have grouped data or master-detail functionality. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm starting to rethink my strategy.  Originally I wanted to provide something like the following:

export class CourseResponse 
{
 status: string;
 courses: Course[];
}

Status could be something like "success", "course not available", "courses coming soon", etc., the latter not necessarily being considered "error conditions".  I guess the approach is not well suited for the push model of Observables which are better for straight up arrays.  Being new to Angular and Ionic, I was trying to model after the "super" CLI sample which includes a status field.